# Como deletar o primeiro e o ultimo nome de uma string

Tags: c#, string

Original:

```
string nome = "João da Conceição Lopes";
```

Resultado esperado:

```
string nomesDoMeio = "da Conceição";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer isso. A mais simples é usar os métodos [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`LastIndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx) combinados com o [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using System;
using static System.Console;        

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string nome = "João da Conceição Lopes";

        //obtém o indíce do primeiro espaço na string
        int i = nome.IndexOf(" ");

        //"corta" a string a partir do primeiro espaço (posição + 1 pra excluir o mesmo)
        nome = nome.Substring(i + 1);
        WriteLine(nome);

        //corta novamente string, começando pela posição 0 e indo até a posição do último espaço
        string nomeMeio = nome.Substring(0, nome.LastIndexOf(" "));
        WriteLine(nomeMeio);
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1dL20J)